# What is the best practice to setState() a class object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, react-hooks

So let's assume I have this code

```
import {useState} from 'react'

class Something{
   counter:number
   constructor(counter:number){
      this.counter = counter
   }
}

function functionalComponent(){
   const [state, setState] = useState<Something>(new Something(5))

   //other codes .....

   function changeState(){
   //see below
   }

   return (
      <>
        <h1>{state.counter}</h1>
        <button onClick={changeState}>Increment</button>
      </>
   )
}

export default functionalComponent
```

Now at some point, I want to change the state to have counter increment 1, the below code works but...

```
   function changeState(){
      state.counter += 1
      setState(state)
   }
```

And before you all start shouting in the comments, I know that we shouldn't mutate the state directly and instead create a new state and pass it on to the setState. But the thing is for js objects and arrays we can simply use the spread operators, but I couldn't find anything simpler for class objects.

So my question is "**What should be the best approach for situations like this?**"

One I could think of and is using

```
   function changeState(){
      let newState = new Something(state.counter+1)
      setState(newState)
   }
```

But it becomes counter productive if my object contains many fields say 15

Comment: Maybe you've simplified this example a bit too much? I don't know, but maybe the question ain't how to do this, but why do you do it that way? What is the purpose of `class Something`? why do you define a class here instead of just using a plain object `useState({ counter: 5 })`? Or in this specific example, just the primitive value `useState(5)`?

Comment: Yeah - like the comment on the answer says, there's not enough information to see what the real use of Something is, which seems to be the core of the issue (it should be refactored out somehow...)

Comment: Hi @Thomas I have updated the question. I think a lot of people were getting confused with the oversimplification

Comment: There is still not enough code to see *how* the `Something` is really being used

Comment: @AjeetShah I know about the js object. The question is about class object and best practices to use it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think now you might be happy

Comment: I am asking why you chose class over an object for this code?

Comment: @AjeetShah to learn about it. We can't have fixated opinions and rather should learn about every approach

Comment: *why you chose class over an object ... to learn about it.* OK. In my experience, at first glance classes and inheritance seem like a neat way to share logic and bring structure to your types. But soon you'll have cases where you want to inherit these parts, but not those, and you start adding intermediate classes for the sole purpose that you can inherit only some methods. Or you want these methods from here, and those from over these, and you start to really bend your code. And then there are the issues with `this`, because JS classes are just a sugarcoating over it's prototypal nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your class inside an object and use the spread operator:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({state:new Something(5)})

state.state.counter = 1
setState({...state})
```

Comment: Why the extra `{ state:` object? This isn't a class component, there's no need to wrap values like that. Also, you're mutating the state here. This is not a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

One Approach that I tried and seems to be close enough is to have a clone function in the class that returns a clone(new Instance). See the below example for a better understanding

```
class Something{
   counter:number
   constructor(counter:number){
      this.counter = counter
   }
   
   clone(){
      return new Something(this.counter)
   }
}
```

So this way whenever I'll call clone it will return a new Instance.
Now in the changeState function, we can do

```
   function changeState(){
      let newState = state.clone()
      newState.counter += 1
      setState(newState)
   }
```

These steps ensures that no where the data is mutated as adheres to the principal of React.

Answer (score 0):

While it would be technically possible to create a new `Something` every time you want to change the state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(5)
const something = useMemo(() => new Something(state), [state]);
```

I'd also first strongly consider whether you need a class inside a functional component at all - it's pretty odd. There's probably a more intuitive solution.

Another option which may or may not work depending on what your *actual* code contains in the class constructor would be to have the state contain an object for all instance properties:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ counter: 5 });
const something = useMemo(() => Object.assign(new Something(), state), [state]);
```

Comment: That's why I said "Let's assume", obviously I'm not creating my class declaration inside the functional component in my project

Comment: Do you mean that the `class` declaration is outside the component (which is fine), or that the `new Something` call is outside the component (which is really weird)? If the second, consider editing the full code into the question - I'm sure there's a better way

Comment: class declaration

Comment: The question is not about any issue, but rather about concept that's why I didn't pasted the whole code. Also I'll be happy to learn what do you mean by the better way

Comment: That's not terrible, just odd. Conceptually, the idea is to avoid classes entirely when possible, and just use ordinary functions inside the component when needed - more details are hard without seeing specifics.

Comment: There's not enough information to see what the real use of `Something` is. General idea would be to refactor it out and use plain objects, arrays, and primitives for state instead. There's (almost) nothing that a class can do that a standard function can't do (and using a standard function is usually better anyway IMO, even outside of React)

Comment: Hi @CertainPerfromance I have updated the question. I think a lot of people were getting confused with the oversimplification

Answer (score 0):

Lets just use useState and functional components it would make your life way easier..